# How to get views based on resolution whilst using composition root in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a scenario where the resolution of target PCs have varied screen resolution. XAML can handle it to some extent but when the resolution varies from 800*600 to 1900*1400 it is best to have two different views/layouts (XAML files).

My application is a MVVM application and I am inclined to use Unity as IOC Container. The code would look something like

```
public partial class App:Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ComposeObjects();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ComposeObjects()
    {
        ......
        ......

        Application.Current.MainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindowView>();
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can resolve MainWindowView and other views based on resolution. I would have couple of views with different layouts for MainWindow UI.

Also, MainWindowView XAMLs would contain reference to many other Views, which may also be required to be resolved based on screen resolution.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest the use of an application framework such as [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) it is designed for composition of WPF views using an MVVM framework. Once you have Prism you would have your main window containing a `Region`, you would then be able to `RequestNavigate` to different views depending upon the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` (in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace). This will return the screen size as a `Rectangle`. 

From here either create multiple Views for your application or change the size of your controls accordingly